# How to resolve issue of mongod not being recognised when developing MEAN stack app?

Tags: angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to create a Node.js backend API for my Angular app.

I've created an *API* folder, & ran the below commands inside it:

```
npm init -y
npm install --save express body-parser cors mongoose
```

I then have a `server.js` inside the *API* folder:

```
const express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cors = require('cors'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const server = app.listen(function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Now, I am trying to connect MongoDB database to the node.js application.

But when I run `mongod` inside the *API* folder, I get the below error:

> The term 'mongod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I tried adding the path to the MongoDB bin folder to my environment variables as a solution, but that has not resolved it.

Also, when I run `mongo --version`, I get MongoDB shell version v4.0.11, so I know it's installed.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong & how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: what do you mean by `run mongod inside the API folder` ?

Comment: I tried running the `mongod` command from inside the folder in the command prompt. I've done a bit more research & tried running it in `C:\Users\MyAccount` & it's created several files in `C:\data\db` but I'm not sure what they are for

Comment: `data\db` is default directory used by mongodb.
else you can define custome directory pathn by `mongod --dbpath DIR`

Answer (score 0):

mongod not recognized means your system doesn't find path for Mongodb installation folder. If you are using windows, do follow below blog

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/install-mongodb